# Vscode on Centos 7.7 does not recognize Intel AVX functions, errors about __mm256i

Tags: visual-studio-code, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I want to use some `avx2` functions by including `<immintrin.h>` library in my project; however, Vscode does not seem to recognize these functions, as it is showing that my project contains various `identifier "__m256i" is undefined` errors as the attached pictures. I can compile and run smoothly, but the errors are really disturbing. I tried adding the declarations of these types into the Vscode path, but it does not help.

I am using the latest Vscode version in Centos 7.7.

[Vscode show errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V76tZ.jpg)

[Try added the include path, but does not help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4dbE.jpg)

Comment: Probably you forgot to use `-march=haswell` or `-march=znver1` to tell the compiler that it can make code that won't work on a CPU *without* AVX2.  The headers won't even define `__m256i` types if AVX isn't enabled at compile time.  (GCC/clang only lets you use intrinsics for instructions that they're allowed to emit, by target options) 
 Also, GCC4.8 is pretty old.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile C++ code with AVX2/AVX512 intrinsics on AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613577/compile-c-code-with-avx2-avx512-intrinsics-on-avx)

Comment: I have just installed GCC 9.2.0, however the problem is not solved. Note that I can compile and run normally, so the problem may come from Vscode itself, such as the include path or something.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that gcc9.2 would solve this problem, just that it was a good idea to get better quality asm generated once you fix it, especially for code using AVX and AVX2 intrinsics.  Rule of thumb: use a compiler newer than the HW you care about tuning for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`__mm256i` is a typo for `__m256i`.**

The type names have 2 underscores and one `m` like `__m128i`
The intrinsic function names have one underscore and 2 ems like like `_mm_add_epi32`

> I can compile and run smoothly, but the errors are really disturbing.

That's highly implausible, are you sure you're not running an old version of your executable from before you introduced this bug in your source?  This is an *error*, not a *warning*; gcc won't produce a `.o` from a source file with this bug.  Hard errors are the opposite of compiling "smoothly".

Comment: I mean, it's not really an error. They are just showed as errors **ONLY** in **Vscode**, and I can compile and run normally using GCC without any error.

Comment: @thnghh: that doesn't make sense.  In what context are you using `__mm256i`?  If it's `__mm256i my_vector`, that's a compile-time error.  I don't know anything about Vscode but I assumed it was summarizing gcc error output.  If not, then that would explain it I guess.

Comment: @thnghh Is this perhaps in a header, which you don't actually include from any source file? Also, if this answer does not solve your issue you should provide a [mre].

Comment: @PeterCordes it's my fault, that should be `__m256i` as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself by restarting my computer. I think somehow at that time the computer did not recognize the definition of Intel AVX functions.